# Why is my increment count button returning [Object object]

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I'm playing around with trying to learn React hooks and I'm trying to write a simple function that increments a count's state.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export const HookCounter = () => {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

    const incrementCount = (count) => {
        setCount(count + 1);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={incrementCount}>Press me!</button>
            <h1>
                You have pressed the button <strong>{count}</strong> times
            </h1>
        </div>
    );
};
```

However, when I click on the button. Instead of the counter incrementing like I would hope it would. I'm instead seeing:

`You have pressed the button [object Object]1 times`.

Why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work correctly is because **you have defined count as an argument which is actually an event** from onClick.

Instead of taking count from closure then, the function takes it from argument since that takes precedence. As event is a object when you try to execute `count + 1`, it stringifies the event object and adds 1 to it giving you `[object Object]1`

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export const HookCounter = () => {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

    const incrementCount = () => { // no count argument here
        setCount(count + 1);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={incrementCount}>Press me!</button>
            <h1>
                You have pressed the button <strong>{count}</strong> times
            </h1>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

@Khatri is right, when you receive count as argument it gets the event object of that button. You can use console.log to print count (I renamed it as event) to check it.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export const HookCounter = () => {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

    const incrementCount = (event) => {
        console.log(event, 'event');
        setCount(count+1);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={incrementCount}>Press me!</button>
            <h1>
                You have pressed the button <strong>{count}</strong> times
            </h1>
        </div>
    );
};
```